# Getting to run more MIPS assembly programs?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'd like to run more MIPS assembly programs. I can run the emulator (MARS) and I can run basic assembly programs. Now I have for instance this program to study, which is OK for my current level:

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "\n Please Input a Value: "
bye: .asciiz "\n Bye!"
.globl main
.text

main:
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt
   syscall

   li $v0, 5
   syscall
   beqz $v0, end
   move $a0, $v0
   li $v0, 1
   syscall
   b main


end:
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, bye
   syscall

   li $v0, 10
   syscall
```

I have 2 book that discuss the theory but they are more about the electronics and how CPU is contructed and not so much teach you how to write complete programs (the books I follow are [Computer Organization and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123747503) and a book in Swedish called [Datorsystem](http://www.bokia.se/datorsystem-4386605) and while these books describe fairly well the background and individual instruction, I need more pointer to complete programs that I can learn from modifying, some similar simple programs with basic i/o like the one above. Since many programs in the books make assumptions that are not realistic e.g. that a certain value already is in a certain register. Practicing on the program above is really good since it is a complete program. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this assumes that you want to become a competent MIPS assembly programmer:

- [See MIPS Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120884216) is the canonical book on MIPS CPUs. This book explains the MIPS instruction set, CPU architecture and how they relate to MIPS Linux.
- Get a MIPS cross compiler toolchain, like the free  [Mentor](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/)/CodeSourcery toolchain, use it to compile your favorite C/C++ programs into MIPS, and study the assembler output.
- You can download and study a MIPS port of Linux from [Timesys](http://www.timesys.com/supported/processors/mips).
- You can find a free and complete MIPS simulator [here](http://www.mips.com/products/system-software/simulator/) (MARS and SPIM are not complete enough for anything more than homework problems). If you want to run MIPS programs on cheap real hardware, start with [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/).